# SortedSet first and Min() are not the same

Tags: .net, sorting, sortedset

First and Min() are not the same
Last and Max() are not the same

In the foreach the sort is
aaa
bbb
ccc
^^

Min()
^^

Max()
cc

How can I get Min() and first to be the same?
How can I get Max() and last to be the same?

ss.FirstOrDefault() is not equal ss.Min()
ss.Reverse().FirstOrDefault() is not equal ss.Max()

```
public void SS()
{
    SortedSet<string> ss = new SortedSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    ss.Add("bbb");
    ss.Add("aaa");            
    ss.Add("^^");
    ss.Add("ccc");
    foreach (string s in ss)
        Debug.WriteLine(s);
    Debug.WriteLine(ss.Min());
    Debug.WriteLine(ss.Max());                   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ss.Min and ss.Max Properties (not Methods).

Comment: Using the `ss.Min` instance property finds the minimal element with respect to the structure of the `SortedSet<string>` and hence respects the comparer carried by that set. However, using the `ss.Min()` LINQ extension method forgets everything about the sorted structure and simply finds the minimal element with respect to the default comparer (that is `Comparer<string>.Default`) which acts exactly like `StringComparer.CurrentCulture`. With "ordinal ignore case", an `a` (U+0061) is treated like an `A` (U+0041) which is _less_ than `^` (U+005E). In your culture, letters are _greater_ than `^`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't.

The longer answer is in the Min implementation, [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Min.cs).

If you're not comparing numbers, the code will use the `Comparer<TSource>.Default`, which is not guaranteed to be the one you are using in the `SortedSet` (and in your case isn't).

BTW, if you just want Min and First to be the same, do not specify a comparer when creating the set. It will use the dafault automatically.

Comment: But I do want that comparison.  Min and Max properties (not method) seem to work.